# Xampp Access Denied (HY000|1045), permissions set

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am  developing php site using xampp and I am having trouble accessing my MySql  database.
I get the following  error:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'guest'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Clothing\index.php on line 24
```

Here is the php code to connect to the database:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'guest', 'Change01&', 'clothing')
```

All the  credentials such as username and password are definitely correct, I have reset the   password  in phpMyAdmin about a thousand times and I still get the error. I have also made  sure the guest user has all  permissions set. What else could be the problem here ? It  might be worth mentioning that I have changed the default ports for Apache but not for MySql.

Comment: Did you allow access to the specified database?

Comment: Yes, the 'guest' user has access to it

Comment: have you added the password manually to config.inc.php.

Comment: @Mikey add information about the privileges you've actually set to your question, otherwise it's just guesswork.

Comment: I have  set all priveleges for that user, I clicked the check all box. I have  set the password in the config file.